# Install Java EE Developer Tool on Eclipse Luna in a virtual machine

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to install JAVA EE Developer Tool(for Dynamic web project) in Eclipse Luna onto my Virtual Machine but unable to see the selection options. Here is the image showing what i am struggling with:

[image]

Comment: Resize the dialog, it is too small.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve the problem in an easy way then you should simply download Eclipse IDE for Java EE developer. You can do that from the links below.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/

If you want to get it from Eclipse Marketplace then you will have to search for webtools platform. Refer to the link below for more information.

https://eclipse.org/webtools/

http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/

To install it, just add the following URL

http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/luna/

If you want to get Eclipse oxygen repository, then you would add the same above url but replace the version name like.

http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/oxygen/